# XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system

Tags: linux, xampp, compatibility, lamp, 32-bit

My xampp suddenly shows this when i run

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

```
XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system.
```

It was working fine yesterday

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating my Manjaro system..
to solve this go to package manager and search for this package
"libxcrypt-compat" then install it..

and that's all, xampp will work fine

Comment: I solved the issue yesterday by uninstalling the xampp server and reinstalling from AUR Store in my Manjari Os.

Answer (score 0):

Instal 32-bit library.

```
yum install glibc*
yum install libstd*
```

For more reference:
https://dankumedia.medium.com/how-to-fix-xampp-is-currently-only-availably-as-32-bit-application-c7d0f4ac9429